# Make form to create other input fields based on what is selected from the onchange from drop down box

Tags: javascript, html

Basically what I want to do is generate certain text boxes depending on which field is selected in the dropdown. I have generic boxes in their right now until I get it to work the way I want hence why it would generate the same box currently.

**HTML :**

```
<form>
    <select>
        <option value="">Field</option>
        <option value="Submitted_By" onchange='whichField("Submitted_By");'>Submitted By</option>
        <option value="Submission_ID">Submission ID</option>
        <option value="File_Name">File Name</option>    
    </select>
    <div id="fieldValue"></div><br>
    <div id="errMsg"></div>
</form>
```

**JS :**

```
function whichField(fid) {
    var fv = document.getElementById("fieldValue");
    if(fid == "Submitted_By") {
        fv.innerHTML = 'Sub by: <input id="field" type="text"></input>';
    } else if(fid == "Submission_ID") {
        fv.innerHTML = 'Sub ID: <input id="field" type="text"></input>';
    } else if(fid == "File_Name") {
        fv.innerHTML = 'File Name: <input id="field" type="text"></input>';
    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error you're seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/csjr2m3y/)** of you example :

**Html changes :**

- Moving **onchange()** function to the select element because we wan't to handle the on change event of all options childs of select.
- Adding **id="select"** for selection if there's many select in your page.

**HTML :**

```
<select id='select' onchange='whichField();'>
    <option value="">Field</option>
    <option value="Submitted_By">Submitted By</option>
    <option value="Submission_ID">Submission ID</option>
    <option value="File_Name">File Name</option>    
</select>
```

**JS changes :**

- Adding two line, the first to getting the **select** targeted and save it into **selectElement**, the second for getting the selected item value to **fid** :

  ```
  var selectElement = document.getElementById("select");
  var fid = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value;
  ```

**JS :**

```
whichField = function() {
    var selectElement = document.getElementById("select");
    var fid = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value;
    var fv = document.getElementById("fieldValue");

    if(fid == "Submitted_By") {
        fv.innerHTML = 'Sub by: <input id="field" type="text"></input>';
    } else if(fid == "Submission_ID") {
        fv.innerHTML = 'Sub ID: <input id="field" type="text"></input>';
    } else if(fid == "File_Name") {
        fv.innerHTML = 'File Name: <input id="field" type="text"></input>';
    } else {
    }
}
```

Hope that this what you looking for.